# Adding Language list in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I m trying to add langauge list in toolbar of CKEditor. So that language can be changed dynamically.But language list is not apperaring in toolbar.please anybody help me to figure out problem.thanks.

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    // config.language = 'fr';
    config.extraPlugins = 'language';
    CKEDITOR.config.toolbar = [
         [ 'language','Bold']
    ];
};
```

Also write plugin.js in `/source/plugins/language/` directory
code:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'language', {
    requires: [ 'selection' ],
    init: function( editor ) {
       var pluginName = 'language';
       CKEDITOR.dialog.add( pluginName, this.path + 'dialogs/language.js' );
       editor.addCommand( pluginName, new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( pluginName ) );
       editor.ui.addButton( 'language', {
           label: 'language',
           command: pluginName
       }
});
```

but not working.Please Anybody help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code that you attached has a lot of syntax errors. Have you checked console?

Here is its fixed version:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'language', {
    requires: 'selection',
    init: function( editor ) {
       var pluginName = 'language';
       CKEDITOR.dialog.add( pluginName, this.path + 'dialogs/language.js' );
       editor.addCommand( pluginName, new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( pluginName ) );
       editor.ui.addButton( 'Language', {
           label: 'language',
           command: pluginName
       });
    }
});
```

Second issue - plugin should be placed in `_source/plugins/language/` directory.

And finally, question - you're trying to create plugin changing language of what? Editor or contents? Note that the first is impossible. Editor has to be reloaded (destroyed and initialized again) to change UI language.

Comment: Actually I am trying to change editor's language.but if its impossible then how can editor's language be changed dynamically?

Comment: To do this dynamically you've got to destroy instance of one editor (`editor.destroy()`) and create new one, with new language, with the same data (so you should first retrieve content of the first editor by `editor.getData()`). That's the only possible way.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help but problem is still there.Selection list is not appearing in toolbar.

Comment: So you need to add it to the toolbar: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbar or http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbarGroups

Comment: Tried all this but even in toolbar button for language is not appearing:(

Comment: Have you added your plugins by e.g. `CKEDITOR.config.extraPlugins = 'language'`? Have you checked your console? It's hard to guess what's wrong without any information.

Comment: yes I tried to add it on both places 'config.js' and in 'fullpage.html' but not working.

Comment: Then I have no idea. You can try to upload your editor with that plugin and then I'll be able to give it a try.

Comment: I have made changes in just to file 'config.js' and in 'source/plugins/language/plugin.js'. this is my edidor's sample http://dl.dropbox.com/u/102119253/ckeditor_3.6.5.rar